# XMLHttpRequest cannot load . Request header field X-CSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps, vuejs2, axios

I tried to use Google maps API to get directions name from coords.
I use Laravel 5.4, vue.js and axios. This is my code

```
 getGeolocation: function () {
    //test if browser supports geolocation
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      //get coords positions
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError);
    } else {
      alert("don't supports");
    }
    function geoSuccess(position) {
      //get params from coords
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var lng = position.coords.longitude;
      //inverse geocodificacion
      axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?',{
        params: {
          latlng: lat+','+lng,
          key: 'KEY-API',
          language: 'es'
        }
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.headers);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    }
    function geoError(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Then, I got this issue:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&latlng=-12.129423599999999,-77.0311565&key=API-KEY&language=es. Request header field X-CSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Someone could help how fix it?

Comment: seems `axios` is adding a header (X-CSRF-TOKEN) that google doesn't like - have you checked axios documentation

Comment: from reading the source code, adding `xsrfCookieName: null` to the config you pass in may help

Comment: by the way, I edited to code so it would "pretty print" correctly :p